# MapStruct not injected in Kotlin project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mapstruct

I am trying to create a project with current Kotlin, MapStruct and Java using Spring-Boot folowing some online examples, as I am new to MapStruct, however I am not able to inject the mapper into my service. Both Idea and Gradle (in build task test) complain that no bean has been found (UnsatisfiedDependencyException). Googling didn't help. What am I missing?

MWE:

**build.gradle.kts**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.14.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.7.20"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final")
    annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**DemoAppllication.kt**

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

**App.kt**

```
package com.example.demo

import org.mapstruct.Mapper
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
class Item(@Id var id: Int = 0)


data class ItemDto(val id: Int)


@Repository
interface ItemRepo : JpaRepository<Item, Int>


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface ItemMapper {
    fun entToDto(item: Item) : ItemDto
    fun entsToDtos(items: List<Item>) : List<ItemDto>
    fun dtoToEnt(itemDto: ItemDto) : Item
}

@Service
class Srvc(private val itemMapper: ItemMapper, // XXX: no bean found for this one
           private val repo: ItemRepo)
{
    fun items() = itemMapper.entsToDtos(repo.findAll())
}

// controller skipped
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kapt is in maintenance mode! See example: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/main/mapstruct-kotlin

```kotlin
plugin {
    // ...
    kotlin("kapt")
    // ...
}
```

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // ...
    kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$version")
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:$version")
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT** (by mpts.cz — for future me or anyone as new to Mapstruct and/or Gradle as I am):

1. use plugin `kotlin("kapt")`
2. replace `annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$version")`
   with `kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$version")`
3. put the previous line before `implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:$version")`

With these changes all seems to work smoothly. Thanks Numichi!

Maybe optionnal but you might need to add the keepJavacAnnotationProcessors with true value, to make things work. Additionally, you might also need to define a global mapstruct config like this:

```
//...
kapt {
  keepJavacAnnotationProcessors = true
  arguments {
     arg("mapstruct.defaultComponentModel", "spring")
    arg("mapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy", "IGNORE")
  }
}
//...
```